# Is there a working R or Python implementation of MGNG (Merge Growing Neural Gas) for temporal anomaly detection?

Tags: python, r, neural-network, time-series, anomaly-detection

I am searching for an implementation of **MGNG** to detect **outliers on multivariate time series data**. The data has structural breaks etc., so I assume this method could work well.

What I found is a C++ implementation (https://talkingrobots.dfki.de/resources/neuralgas/), but the manual is huge and there are no examples. A Python or R API would be great.